# Scala, Play framework, Specs2, Mockito, what is the correct way to verify order of calls?

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, specs2

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/UsingMockito) document to verify order of calls we need:

```
val m1 = mock[List[String]]
val m2 = mock[List[String]]

m1.get(0)
m1.get(0)
m2.get(0)

here was one(m1).get(0) then one(m1).get(1)
```

With my code

```
...
  val db = mock[Database]

  "The code" should {

    "Should do something" in {
      val id = "id"
      db.readUserByid(anyString) returns None

      val rv = api.login(id)

      there was one(db).readUserByid(id) then one(db).createUser(anyString)
    }
  }
...
```

I get an error

> value then is not a member of
>   org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Option[models.domain.user.User]]

and a warning

> then is now a reserved word; usage as an identifier is deprecated

I'm using Play framework 2.2.0,
Specs2 bundled with this version of Play,
Mockito 1.9.5

Could you please point out to a correct document what contains information about verifying order of calls?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`andThen`](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Order+of+calls)

```
there was one(db).readUserByid(id) andThen one(db).createUser(anyString)
```